# use if else between 2 route in laravel in web.php

Tags: laravel, if-statement, routes

I have two route in laravel. Once have id based and other don't need id in route,That means when click on a menu a web route i setup and when i click another menu link i use another route.is it possible?
Here is my rout list.

Route::get('/invoice/add', 'InvoiceAdd')->name('invoice.add');
this route works only i click a menu like 'invoice'

Route::get('/invoice/add/id', 'InvoiceAdd')->name('invoice.add');
this route works only when i pass a id from a link.

I want to use like this

if(get link pass with a id)
{  Route::get('/invoice/add/{id}', 'InvoiceAdd')->name('invoice.add'); }

else
{ Route::get('/invoice/add/', 'InvoiceAdd')->name('invoice.add'); }

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do that? If you want the route parameter that is optional. You can do:

```
Route::get('/invoice/add/{id?}', 'InvoiceAdd')->name('invoice.add');
```

Comment: Thanks. But i need those two route one needs "id" another except "id"